# D6 to D7 re-coding for tokens issue in Ubercart

Tags: drupal-7, token, ubercart

There are these two token statements below in a module being ported to Drupal 7 that no one supports any longer in which the functions called have been replaced - but I do not know how to reformulate the code to the new functions

At my line 168 of the module is this one below which is part of `hook_token_values()` implementation in Drupal 6.

```
foreach (uc_store_token_values('global') as $token => $value) {
  $values['order-' . $token] = $value;
 }
```

AND at line 350

```
 foreach (uc_store_token_values('global') as $token => $value) {
   $vars[str_replace('-', '_', $token)] = $value;
 }
```

The function "uc_store_token_values" is gone in Drupal 7 and it is "uc_store_tokens".

AND the switch case token $type 'global' no longer exists - the new switch case is (would be) 'store' it appears, and returns an array now called $replacements - which otherwise is largely the same as the array $values

hook_token_values() in D6 is also gone and is NOW simply called as  hook_tokens() in D7

I am not familiar with tokens.  See also what has happened to others at https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/token/update/6/7

so if I change uc_store_token_values to uc_store_tokens and 'global' to 'store' - the error is " Missing argument 2 for uc_store_tokens(), called in . . . module on line 342 and defined in uc_store_tokens() (line 72 of . . . /uc_store.tokens.inc) which is =>  function uc_store_tokens($type, $tokens, $data = array(), $options = array()) {   There entire function can be found as a uc_store_tokens search for Drupal 7)

So it appears argument 2 is "$tokens" of which there was no argument 2 and did not exist in uc_store_token_values in Drupal 6 and is apparently supposed to be an or the array of tokens to be replaced according to the Drupal 7 hook_tokens function API)

So the question is does anyone here know how are the two pieces of code above from 168 and 350 changed to comply with the new `uc_store_tokens()`?

Answer (score 0):

"The hooks for providing tokens have been renamed. hook_token_list() is now hook_token_info(), and hook_token_values() is now hook_tokens(). Both hooks also have changed parameters and different return values than their D6 equivalents." THIS FROM => https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/token/update/6/7

It then also says "There is currently no upgrade path between the old token names in Drupal 6 and the new chainable-style tokens in Drupal 7. Some helper functions are being written in token.module."

Clearly then the module functions must be modified and some sample code can be found at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/how-to-programmatically-create-a-custom-token-in-a-module and https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86136/formatting-output-of-token and at drupal.org in the function token_info documentation